# Why does changing the innerHTML, of my box, make my button stop working in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, innerhtml

So, I wrote a script that loads images one at a time in a new tab... Got a stop button to work thanks to Brock over [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26418958/996364)...

Then I broke it adding in the counter that I had written in while waiting for an answer to that question.

I can't see any reason that should have broke it... help please?

My Script:

```
var box = document.createElement ('div');
box.id = 'mySelectBox';
GM_addStyle (
    ' #mySelectBox {             ' +
    '    background: white;     ' +
    '    border: 2px solid red; ' +
    '    padding: 4px;          ' +
    //'    position: absolute;    ' +
    '    position: fixed;       ' +
    '    top: 8px; left: 8px;   ' +
    '    max-width: 400px;      ' +
    ' } '
);
document.body.appendChild (box);
box.innerHTML = '';

var searchButton = document.createElement ('div');
searchButton.className = 'mySearchButton';
searchButton.textContent = 'Open';

GM_addStyle (
    ' .mySearchButton {           ' +
    '    background: #aaa;       ' +
    '    border: 1px solid #777; ' +
    '    padding: 1px;           ' +
    '    margin-left: 8px;       ' +
    '    float: right;           ' +
    '    cursor: pointer;        ' +
    ' } '
);
box.insertBefore (searchButton, box.nextSibling);

var stopButton = document.createElement ('div');
stopButton.className = 'myStopButton';
stopButton.textContent = 'Stop';

GM_addStyle (
    ' .myStopButton {           ' +
    '    background: #aaa;       ' +
    '    border: 1px solid #777; ' +
    '    padding: 1px;           ' +
    '    margin-left: 8px;       ' +
    '    float: right;           ' +
    '    cursor: pointer;        ' +
    ' } '
);
box.insertBefore (stopButton, box.nextSibling);

var closeButton = document.createElement ('div');
closeButton.className = 'myCloseButton';
closeButton.textContent = 'X';

GM_addStyle (
    ' .myCloseButton {           ' +
    '    background: #aaa;       ' +
    '    border: 1px solid #777; ' +
    '    padding: 1px;           ' +
    '    margin-left: 8px;       ' +
    '    float: right;           ' +
    '    cursor: pointer;        ' +
    ' } '
);

box.insertBefore (closeButton, box.firstChild);
closeButton.addEventListener ('click', function () {
    box.parentNode.removeChild (box);
}, true);

var mytable = document.getElementById

    ('lair-sort-pets').getElementsByTagName ('img');

var linksToOpen = [];
var mywin2 = null;

var okayToOpenLinks = true;

searchButton.addEventListener ('click', openpics);
stopButton.addEventListener ('click', stopLinkSequence);

function openpics () {
    okayToOpenLinks = true;

    if (linksToOpen.length === 0) {
        for (var J = 0, L = mytable.length; J < L; J++) {

            linksToOpen.push (mytable[J].src); //-- Add URL to list
        }
    }

    openLinksInSequence ();
};

original = box.innerHTML

function stopLinkSequence () {
    okayToOpenLinks = false;
}

function openLinksInSequence () {
    k = linksToOpen.length - 1

    if (mywin2) {
        mywin2.close ();
        mywin2 = null;
    }

    if (okayToOpenLinks && linksToOpen.length) {
        var link = linksToOpen.shift ();
        mywin2 = window.open (link, "my_win2");

        box.innerHTML = '<center>Links left</center><br>' + '<center>' + k + '</center><br>' + original;

        mywin2.addEventListener ('load', openLinksInSequence, false);
    }
}
```

If I comment out this line it works again (except no status counter):

```
box.innerHTML = '<center>Links left</center><br>'+'<center>'+k+'</center><br>'+original;
```

WHY?

[HERE](http://www.aywas.com/lair/group/6432/unsorted/?p=4&l=32)  is a possible target page for the Greasemonkey script.

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work on dialup for me... sorry

Comment: I added the box and button code for you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change an element's contents using `innerHTML` (or `outerHTML`), [it trashes any event handlers of anything that element contained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2947012/331508).  It can also help cause performance problems and memory leaks.  Don't use `innerHTML` in userscripts except maybe for the *initial creation* of brand new nodes.

For a countdown/status display, create the HTML once, then just alter the data content and/or use CSS to alter the display.  Doing that, and sanitizing things a bit, that code becomes:

```
var box         = document.createElement ('div');
document.body.appendChild (box);    // Must append before set outerHTML
box.outerHTML   = multilineStr ( function () {/*!
    <div id="mySelectBox">
        <div id="myStatus">Links left<br>
            <span>86</span>
        </div>
        <div id="myCloseButton">X</div>
        <div id="mySearchButton">Open</div>
    </div>
*/} );

document.getElementById ("myCloseButton").addEventListener ('click', function () {
    var box = this.parentNode;
    box.parentNode.removeChild (box);
} );
var startStopBtn    = document.getElementById ("mySearchButton");
startStopBtn.addEventListener ('click', startStopPicsLoad);

var mytable         = document.querySelectorAll ('#lair-sort-pets img');
var linksToOpen     = [];
var mywin2          = null;
var okayToOpenLinks = true;

function startStopPicsLoad () {
    if (typeof startStopPicsLoad.isStartBtn === "undefined") {
        startStopPicsLoad.isStartBtn    = true;
    }
    if (startStopPicsLoad.isStartBtn) {
        //-- Change start button to stop button
        startStopBtn.textContent        = "Stop";
        startStopPicsLoad.isStartBtn    = false;

        if (linksToOpen.length === 0) {
            for (var J = 0, L = mytable.length; J < L; J++) {
                linksToOpen.push (mytable[J].src); //-- Add URL to list
            }

            //-- Display the status area.
            document.querySelector ('#myStatus').style.display = "block";
        }

        openLinksInSequence ();
    }
    else {
        //-- Change stop button to start button
        startStopBtn.textContent        = "Open";
        startStopPicsLoad.isStartBtn    = true;

        //-- Actually stop the sequence.
        okayToOpenLinks = false;
    }
};

function openLinksInSequence () {
    if (mywin2) {
        mywin2.close ();
        mywin2 = null;
    }

    if (okayToOpenLinks) {
        if (linksToOpen.length) {
            var k           = linksToOpen.length - 1;
            var statDisp    = document.querySelector ('#myStatus span');
            statDisp.textContent = k;

            var link        = linksToOpen.shift ();
            mywin2          = window.open (link, "my_win2");
            mywin2.addEventListener ('load', openLinksInSequence, false);
        }
    }
    else {
        //-- Sequence is now stopped, reset the state variable.
        okayToOpenLinks = true;
    }
}

GM_addStyle ( multilineStr ( function () {/*!
    #mySelectBox {
        background: white;
        border: 2px solid red;
        padding: 4px;
        //position: absolute;
        position: fixed;
        top: 8px; left: 8px;
        max-width: 400px;
    }
    #myStatus {
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
    }
    #myCloseButton {
        background: #aaa;
        border: 1px solid #777;
        padding: 1px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #mySearchButton {
        background: #aaa;
        border: 1px solid #777;
        padding: 1px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
*/} ) );

function multilineStr (dummyFunc) {
    var str = dummyFunc.toString ();
    str     = str.replace (/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '') // Strip function() { /*!
            .replace (/\s*\*\/\s*\}\s*$/, '')   // Strip */ }
            .replace (/\/\/.+$/gm, '') // Double-slash comments wreck CSS. Strip them.
            ;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: It actually didn't cause a pileup...  all it did was disable the stop button... but the counter was working perfectly...  (maybe you missed the line near the beginning where I set 'original' - before I did that they did pile up if I used 'innerHTML + k' and if I didn't use 'innerHTML +'it ate the buttons lol)... I see you also changed my 'getElements' - explain? This is so much more complicated than my version... Now to understand it before I use it...   THANK YOU!

Comment: Oops. Sorry about the "pileup" mixup.  That's what I get for "testing" that part of the code in my head. ;) ... ... That "getElements" usage was "time-bomb code" since the return value of the stack wasn't checked. `querySelector` is far superior for that kind of thing, and it uses standard CSS selectors (which you need to know anyway) to grab elements.

Comment: I updated Firefox and Greasemonkey recently and this script no longer works... the start button loads the first image but won't close it, and then if I hit stop, then hit start the image tab closes and then nothing - no error codes.  Has anything changed since Firefox 24 that might be causing this?  Or in the newest Greasemonkey?  Or do I need to look at my numerous updated addons?

Comment: Yes, quite a bit has changed.  I don't see anything obvious that would break in this script, though. ... Add `// @grant GM_addStyle` to your header/metadata block.  If that doesn't work, boil the problem down to an MCVE and ask a new question.

Comment: Darn.... thanks anyways... // @grant GM_addStyle is already there because it's being used lol... so no easy fix - this'll be fun.... I DID read something about window.close() being changed in Firefox 35 (or somewhere around there) but I assume you would've noticed if it was something like that... this is why I don't ever upgrade... it broke another script too, finally rewrote it from scratch with more jquery - probably rewrite this one too.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Ahah! Error: Permission denied to access property "addEventListener" Now to figure out why.... in this line: mywin2.addEventListener ('load', openLinksInSequence, false); or this one: mywin2= window.open (link, "my_win2");

Comment: Okay, that might be a PITA to get around in newer Firefox.  Forgot about window open/close changes.  And you have to keep up with upgrades. Otherwise, you'll get infected just by *viewing* web pages and without even knowing it. And AV programs always miss "zero day" attacks too.  Make a new Q with an MCVE, if needed.

Comment: I have a script that uses a jqueryui modal window to go through the links on a page with a next button... I may be able to use that as a basis,  and I prefer the modal to the new tab anyways.  Viruses don't worry me - I have a side job repairing computers and have yet to find the virus that can beat me (although I still haven't gotten around to installing the Ransom virus on my test computer).  I keep hearing you can get viruses just by viewing a page but I haven't found one yet that doesn't require pressing a button. I haven't had a virus in years. And I don't even run a resident scanner.