# An Easier Way to Create a DOM Tree in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, userscripts

Working on a userscript for this site so the only way I can add elements is to do so with JavaScript. Currently it's simple stuff, but a lot of it, and I was hoping for a way to cut down on code.

I've got this:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('main'),
    nav = document.createElement('nav'),
    ul = document.createElement('ul'),
    l1 = document.createElement('li'),
    l2 = document.createElement('li'),
    l3 = document.createElement('li'),
    l4 = document.createElement('li'),
    l5 = document.createElement('li'),
    l6 = document.createElement('li'),
    l7 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest2 = document.createElement('ul'),
    nest3 = document.createElement('ul'),
    nest4 = document.createElement('ul'),
    nest2L1 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest2L2 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest2L3 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest3L1 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest3L2 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest3L3 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest3L4 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest4L1 = document.createElement('li'),
    nest4L2 = document.createElement('li');

nav.id = 'ps-nav';
    ul.id = 'ps-ul';
        l1.id = 'ps-announcements';
        l1.className = 'ps-listItem';
        l2.id = 'ps-sponge';
        l2.className = 'ps-listItem';
            nest2.id = 'ps-sponge-nest';
            nest2.className = 'ps-nest';
        l3.id = 'ps-plugins';
        l3.className = 'ps-listItem';
            nest3.id = 'ps-plugins-nest';
            nest3.className = 'ps-nest';
        l4.id = 'ps-generalDiscussion';
        l4.className = 'ps-listItem';
            nest4.id = 'ps-generalDiscussion';
            nest4.clasName = 'ps-nest';
        l5.id = 'ps-serverDiscussion';
        l5.className = 'ps-listItem';
        l6.id = 'ps-meta';
        l6.className = 'ps-listItem';
        l7.id = 'ps-uncategorized';
        l7.className = 'ps-listItem';

elm.appendChild(nav);
    nav.appendChild(ul);
        ul.appendChild(l1);
        ul.appendChild(l2);
            l2.appendChild(nest2);
                nest1.appendChild(nest2L1);
                nest1.appendChild(nest2L2);
                nest1.appendChild(nest2L3);
        ul.appendChild(l3);
            l3.appendChild(nest3);
                nest2.appendChild(nest3L1);
                nest2.appendChild(nest3L2);
                nest2.appendChild(nest3L3);
                nest2.appendChild(nest3L4);
        ul.appendChild(l4);
            l4.appendChild(nest4);
                nest3.appendChild(nest4L1);
                nest3.appendChild(nest4L2);
        ul.appendChild(l5);
        ul.appendChild(l6);
        ul.appendChild(l7);
```

I've nested the indentation for higher readability.
How can I reduce the amount of code here achieving the same affect?

Comment: Create it in HTML, not Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar I can't do this. It's a userscript.

Comment: @Spedwards: You can put the HTML in a string, and then put it in the innerHTML of the element you want it appended to?

Comment: You can use `elm.innerHTML += 'string of HTML'`

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I actually overlooked `innerHTML`...

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript:

1. Create the container.
2. Attach it to the page.
3. Overwrite the container's `outerHTML`.  This can be done with a multiline string.
4. Use [GM_addStyle()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle) to set or change the CSS.

Like so:

```
var elm = document.getElementById ('main');
var nav = document.createElement ('nav');
elm.appendChild (nav);

nav.outerHTML   = multilineStr ( function () {/*!
    <nav id="ps-nav">
        <ul id="ps-ul">
            <li id="ps-announcements" class="ps-listItem">Hiya!</li>

            // ETC., ETC.
        </ul>
    </nav>
*/} );

//-- Reaquire `nav` variable, if desired.
nav = document.getElementById ('ps-nav');


function multilineStr (dummyFunc) {
    var str = dummyFunc.toString ();
    str     = str.replace (/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '') // Strip function() { /*!
            .replace (/\s*\*\/\s*\}\s*$/, '')   // Strip */ }
            .replace (/\/\/.+$/gm, '') // Double-slash comments wreck CSS. Strip them.
            ;
    return str;
}
```

See, also, ["Why does changing the innerHTML, of my box, make my button stop working in Greasemonkey?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26420444/331508) and similar questions.

---

The jQuery equivalent is:

```
$("#main").append (multilineStr ( function () {/*!
    <nav id="ps-nav">
        <ul id="ps-ul">
            <li id="ps-announcements" class="ps-listItem">Hiya!</li>

            // ETC., ETC.
        </ul>
    </nav>
*/} ) );

//-- Reaquire `nav`, if desired.
var nav = $('#ps-nav');

function multilineStr (dummyFunc) {
    var str = dummyFunc.toString ();
    str     = str.replace (/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '') // Strip function() { /*!
            .replace (/\s*\*\/\s*\}\s*$/, '')   // Strip */ }
            .replace (/\/\/.+$/gm, '') // Double-slash comments wreck CSS. Strip them.
            ;
    return str;
}
```